# How to create date occurrence between two dates by giving days gap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have the below data:

1 year contract

```
Start Date: 01-01-2019

End Date: 31-12-2019
```

15 days gap between start and end date exclude all Fridays

**Exact Expected output exclude all Fridays**

```
19-01-2019 //exclude Fridays then got 19 jan 2019
-----------
05-02-2019 //after 15 days
-----------
23-02-2019 //after 15 days
-------------
keep on adding.. hit until end month 12-2019
```

How to generate it?Is there a better approach for doing this?

```
var start = new Date("2019-01-01");
var end = new Date("2019-12-31");

while (start <= end) {
    console.log( new Date(start) );
    start.setMonth( start.getMonth() + 1 );
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

from your use case, it seems that Friday is a non-working day and you would like to print the 15th day based on the start date.

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
return date; }

function printNextPeriod(startDate, endDate, periodInDays) {
var numWorkDays = 0;
var currentDate = new Date(startDate);
while (numWorkDays < periodInDays && currentDate <= endDate) {
    currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
    // Skips friday
    if (currentDate.getDay() !== 5) {
        numWorkDays++;
    }
    if (numWorkDays == periodInDays) {
        numWorkDays = 0;
        console.log(currentDate);
    }
} }
```

`var start = new Date("2019-01-01");
var end = new Date("2019-12-31");
var period = 15;
printNextPeriod(start, end, period);`

Comment: Awesome!!!..How will i format like 19-Jan-2019 without showing sat and GMT

Comment: I want to show this in a html table with Column name Date then values will be 19-Jan-2019, 05-Feb-2019...so on

Comment: is it possible to skip Holidays also??Assume i have set of holiday list in database..holidays will not comes to the result date.I want to skip the holiday date and skip to next date is fine

Comment: if holiday is 19-jan-2019 then skip this date and need to show 20-jan-2019(exclude Fridays)..Then next 15 days will be 06-Feb-2019 (15days calculating from 21st Jan)

Comment: for example var holidays = array("2019-01-19", "2019-02-22", "2019-12-25"");

Comment: ISO 8601 dates are parsed as UTC, but you're using local methods so you'll get difficult to find errors for users west of Greenwich (e.g. 2019-08-21 UTC will be 2019-08-20 local in New York). `new Date(this.valueOf());` can be `new Date(this)`, there's no need for *valueOf*.

Comment: How to start with the date 2019-01-01?